# How to pin a website to windows taskbar programmatically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't use drag and drop method. I have gone through the jquery pinify plugin, but what I understood is that, it only encourage user to pin website using drag and drop using intelligent popups rather than doing it on it's own. 
Is this even possible?

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: It's not possible due to security reasons.

Comment: As per my knowledge this is not possible. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No luckily this is not possible.

Imagine the security reasons behind it. No website can change something on your OS. (At least that's what we all hope, that's why I say "luckily" we have a problem if this would not be like so).

Or imagine this: You create a website. The font is defined by designers and project managers which discussed which font and which font-size will be the best to represent the company on the web. So you created the website based on those requirements. But now, I have some issues with my eyes. This is why I setup my browser with a default font-size. This is what I need, to read any content from the web. Now, **NO! You can not change this!** Why? Because I have set something in my browser settings, also those are part of my "personal" settings. You can not look into them and you obviously can not change them. Hope this helps.